# is there any symbols forbidden in run_id?

Tags: wandb

I just started working with wandb. I am curious if there is any requirement in the format of the run_id (e.g. cannot contain brackets '[]' or '()')

the reason why I am asking is that I cannot log my runs (image data) properly after adding a '[..]' prefix to my run_id. There is no modification in the code which could lead to this problem and the wandb version remain the same.

Would be great if anyone could gives some clue in this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you share minimal code to reproduce this? I was able to add brackets into `name` and `id` when calling `wandb.init`. [image: run name and id with brackets]

Update: All punctuation characters are allowed in `name`. All except: `/\#?%:` are allowed in `id`.